# How to organize the product properties in the catalog if each category has a different set of properties (wp all import)?

Tags: wordpress, web, wpallimport, online-store

I make a parser that collects a catalog from the store in csv format for subsequent import into wordpress post type(unyson). In the catalog, each category has a different set of characteristics. As I understand it, it is necessary to collect all possible characteristics from the catalog in a csv table and create a column in csv for each of them, and already display only those columns on the site that are used by at least one entry.

I thought to store json with all the characteristics for each product, but then it will not be possible to implement filtering on Wordpress.
What options can you offer? I hope the essence of the question is clear.
I don't use woocommerce before. Only heard about it. Maybe it has suitable features?